# Getting Mouse Pointer location across system

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to get the Mouse Pointer Location across all Application i.e., Not specific to application,

For Eg: I Want to Get the Mouse Pointer Location On the screen which is not specific to corresponding Application.

Thanks in advance
dinesh

Comment: I don't know abt static Cursor.Position. But I need to move the cursor to out of the Appliction. In our case say out of Window. Is that posible in C# ?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the static `Cursor.Position` property.

Comment: I don't know abt static Cursor.Position. But I need to move the cursor to out of the Appliction. In our case say out of Window. Is that posible in C# ?

Comment: @dinesh: Yes; you're looking for the static `Cursor.Position` property.  Retyping your question doesn't change the answer.